# Magento disable Customer Account links?

Tags: magento-1.8, customer

I need to disable all customer account related pages, `like Account info, Edit addresses, change password for customers of a specific Magento store`. Basically I want the customers on that specific store, to just login, register, view products and buy the same only.

And I also do not want to send any welcome email to customers who register on this store.

I tried to find the solution, but could only find solutions to hide the links, but some customers might end up opening them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this through xml.

```
<customer_account>
         <reference name="left">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer_account_navigation</name></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account>
```

this is second solution if you want to to specific website

**Step 1:** Go to ( yourPackage/YourTemplate/customer/account/navigation.phtml )

**Step 2:** Replace the below line

> ```
> <?php $count = count($links); ?>
> ```

```
        **With**
```

> ```
> <?php $_count = count($_links); /* Add or Remove Account Left
>      $website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
>         if($website_id = 1):
>       unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */     
>       unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */            
>       unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
>       unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
>       unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
>       unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
>       unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
>       unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
>       unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
>       unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
>       unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
>       unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
>       unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
>       unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
>       unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
>       unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
>       unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
>          endif;
> ?>Navigation Links Here -*/
> ```

Comment: can you tell me how to do it for specific store/website only?

Comment: you can use second solution for that...

Comment: can you please explain exactly what that does? it will not display the links or if I even type the links directly into browser, it wont let customer use them? Moreover cant we add some website id or name in xml you had provided first?

Comment: it will not display the link. for permanent disable you have to override the controller. and you use `helper="mymodule/canShowIf"` in you action to conditional remove.